# COUNTIF operation in R across multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform the COUNTIF operation in R, for multiple columns. The columns I need to perform them on are named d1, d2,...d9. For one column, this formula works:

```
data <- data %>% 
  add_count(d1, name = "count_d1")
```

However, when I try the following loop to replicate this for all columns at once, it doesn't work:

```
allcols <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9")
for (j in allcols) {
  data <- data %>% 
    add_count(allcols[j], name = paste("count_",allcols[j], sep = ""))
}
```

This just adds one column named **allcols[j]** to the data frame, and the corresponding count column is named **count_NA** (instead of multiple columns named **count_d1**, **count_d2**, etc).

How do I need to modify my code?

Comment: Try this: `for (j in allcols) {
  data <- data %>% 
    add_count(!!sym(j), name = paste("count_", j, sep = ""))
}`

Comment: edit your for loop to `for(j in 1: length(allcols)){ your code here}`

Comment: @RezaEsmaeelzade ah yes, you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is that when you use allcols[j] within the loop, it is interpreted as a character string instead of the column name you intend to use. To fix this, you can use the !!sym() function to convert the character string to a column name. Here's the modified code that should work:

```
allcols <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9")
for (j in allcols) {
  data <- data %>% 
    add_count(!!sym(j), name = paste("count_",j, sep = ""))
}
```

In this code, `!!sym(j)` will evaluate to the column name represented by the character string j.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `across/pick`

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
library(stringr)
allcols <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9")
for(j in allcols)
{
data <- data %>%
     add_count(pick(all_of(j)), name = str_c("count_", j))
}
```

---

Or another option is to do this in `across` itself

```
data %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(allcols), 
     ~ tibble(nm1 = .x) %>%
        add_count(nm1) %>% 
       pull(n), .names = "count_{.col}")) %>%
   as_tibble
```

---

A reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
data <- mtcars
out1 <- data %>% 
   mutate(across(c(vs, am , gear), ~ tibble(nm1 = .x) %>% 
   add_count(nm1) %>%
    pull(n), .names = "count_{.col}")) %>%
   as_tibble

allcols <- c("vs", "am", "gear")
out2 <- data
for(j in allcols)
{
out2 <- out2 %>%
     add_count(pick(all_of(j)), name = str_c("count_", j))
}
> all.equal(out1, out2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```